# Failed to Resolve: com.android.support.customtabs

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I get an error even though I added:

```
maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'}
```

how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx):

> [Version 28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#28-0-0) is the last release of the Support Library. There will be no more `android.support` library releases. All new feature development will be in the `androidx` namespace.

Therefore it is expected that there is no `29.+` version of any `com.android.support` library. You should [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).